# Unable to find a element in a page. Inspect Element shows different HTML than source page Python - Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate an element on a page. If I do Inspect Element, I can see the HTML code and the element `id = username`, but when I view page source, there is only `Javascript` code. Any idea on how to see the HTML page instead?

This is the page: https://pje.tjmg.jus.br/pje/login.seam

That is my code:

```
username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username')))
username_input.clear()
username_input.send_keys(cpf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Username* field is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://pje.tjmg.jus.br/pje/login.seam")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#ssoFrame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username"))).send_keys("MPenner")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://pje.tjmg.jus.br/pje/login.seam")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ssoFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']"))).send_keys("MPenner")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: MPenner]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

It's inside an iframe.

```
<iframe id="ssoFrame" name="ssoFrame" class="sso-frame" src="https://pje.tjmg.jus.br/pje/authenticateSSO.seam"></iframe>
```

Try the page in the iframe instead: https://pje.tjmg.jus.br/pje/authenticateSSO.seam

Answer (score 0):

Desired element(`@id=username`) is wrapped within an `iframe`. You first need to switch into the `iframe` and then perform any action.

[image]

**Refer the below working code:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://pje.tjmg.jus.br/pje/login.seam")
wait= WebDriverWait(driver,30)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"ssoFrame")))
username_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username')))
username_input.clear()
username_input.send_keys("text")
time.sleep(30)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Switching back to default content:** To come out of `iframe` use the code below.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```